# Elasticsearch must with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am beginner programmer in python. Now I have integrated Elasticseach 6.8.1 version with python and now I have to delete data from elasticsearch using pyhton language. For this I have written following query

```
 query = {'bool':{'must':[
                {'term':{'db_id':25}},
                {'terms': {'type': ['user_likes','likes']}}
            ]}}
es_client.delete_by_query(index="user_likes", doc_type='doc', body=query)
```

When I run this query I get following error

> {RequestError}RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'Unknown key for
> a START_OBJECT in [bool].')

I did not found in example the how I can use must with multiple condition for delete_by_query. how I can execute this query for delete_by_query?

Comment: this error is not bcoz of any mistake in python , there is mistake in your query . please share any 1 document from your `elasticsearch index` & what is your expected output.

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat I have updated the query I simply need to delete the data by using this I query which I write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change what you have declared as `query` to this :

```
 query = {'query': 
           {'bool':
              {'must':[
                {'term':{'db_id':int(model['id'])}},
                {'terms': {'type': ['user_likes','likes']}}
        ]}}
    }
```

What I have done is just added `query` parameter - inside which `bool` has to appear, but you have directly kept `bool` I am guessing that would be the problem.
If it doesn't work still, provide more details about your data & expected output